# For $A_1, A_2 \in {^\omega 2}$, if $ \langle A_1, A_2 \rangle$ is Cohen generic over $N$ then so is $\langle A_1'', A_2 \rangle$.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I'm reading through the following article,

*Shelah, Saharon*, [**Can the fundamental (homotopy) group of a space be the rationals?**](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-103-02/S0002-9939-1988-0943095-3/S0002-9939-1988-0943095-3.pdf), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 103, No. 2, 627-632 (1988). [ZBL0661.55012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0661.55012).

from which I have the following question. I try to extract out my question but if that has caused missing critical information please let me know.

Let $ \mathscr{E} \subset {^\omega 2} \times {^\omega 2}$ be a relation, and suppose $N$ is a countable elementary submodel of $ \big\langle H \big( (2^{\aleph_0})^+ \big), \mathscr{E} \big\rangle $. Let $ A_1, A_2 \in {^\omega 2}$ (with the representation as subsets of the naturals) such that $ \langle A_1 , A_2 \rangle $ is Cohen generic over $N$; which is mentioned it's topologically equivalent to saying that $\langle A_1, A_2 \rangle$ does not belong to any meagre subset of $ {^\omega 2} \times {^\omega 2} $ like $M$ that $M \in N$. Fix some $n \in \omega$ (this $n$ is technically derived but I think it's explanation is unnecessary for this question) and let $A_1''$ be $A_1 \cup \{n+1\}$ if $ n+1 \notin A_1$ and $A_1 \setminus \{n+1 \}$ if $n+1 \in A_1$. It is stated that *trivially* $ \langle A_1'', A_2 \rangle $ is also Cohen generic over $N$; but I can't figure this out. Is this something clear that I'm missing or the triviality only comes up if we look at it from forcing's perspective?

Comment: Instead of forcing me to download a PDF, you can just as well tell me the name of the article and who wrote it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Isn't that just about a click? I would like to know how this could be inconvenient.

Comment: Not if you're using your mobile it's not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. So I edited the question and would also consider it for future questions.

Comment: We also have an "insert citation" feature, by the way. To make all of this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map that transforms $(A,B)$ into $(A'',B)$ is a homeomorphism of $2^\omega\times2^\omega$ that exists in $N$. In particular, the preimage of a meager set is meager.

If $(A_1'', A_2)$ is not Cohen over $N$ it is an element of a meager set coded in $N$. But so is $(A_1,A_2)$.

Comment: Did you mean "hits" rather than "misses"? And that meager set should be (coded) in $N$.